# Numbers equal to the sum of powers of its digits, need faster python code

Tags: digits

In Python, create a function finding all  integers between 1  and 1.000.000.000, which are equal to the sum of k'th power of its digits for some k.

**Example:** 4150 = 4^5 + 1^5 + 5^5 + 0^5.

Here is my code working perfect until 1.000.000. However, it becomes so slow for large numbers. I try Numpy but it  does not work. Any improvement would be welcome. ^^ (Any library or python function you may use)

```
def powers(n):
s = []
for number in range(1, 10 ** n):
    number_list = [int(x) for x in str(number)]
    if max(number_list) > 1:
        total = 0
        power = 1
        while total < number:
            total = sum([y ** power for y in number_list])
            if total == number:
                s.append((number, power))
            power += 1
return s
```

Comment: Same power for all digits? How about picking a power, picking the digits to try and verifying that the number you built has only the right digits in it? So for a constant power P you have to check all possible subsets of digits (`2**10` possibilities, about a thousand). How many powers do you have to check? `2**30` > 1e9 and higher digits will exceed the limit with smaller powers so it's 30 at maximum. At most 30000 numbers to check should definitely be more feasible than going through one billion numbers.

Comment: This might do better on codereview SE.

Comment: it is s edited, yes  same power. After my code  is running so long, I see that the maximum required power for 8 digits integers is 8. And so, I will try to find a better bound for k, which seems to be interesting in terms of mathametic. I should say that what you suggest seems more reasanable for the code to work faster. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, my approach seems to work ok, I got [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 4150, 69950, 69951, 91818, 93084, 99836, 24678050, 24678051, 43509443, 67658979, 533689233] in 80 ms. It looks like an assignment, so no code for you, but it should be enough of a hint.

Comment: it is not anassignment but hobby. i will try that challenge . Ty for giving  time of your code ^^

Comment: @dratenik I'm not sure I understand your solution. "you have to check all possible subsets of digits (2**10 possibilities, about a thousand)". Lets say I check for the power of 3. Now I want to pick all subsets of the set [0^3, 1^3, 2^3, ..., 9^3]? But finding all subsets of that set seems to me to be a billion subsets, since a number may repeat, not just a thousand. What am I missing?

Comment: @Scratte see [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), example power is 3, example subset let's say {0,1,4,6,9}, `0**3+1**3+4**3+6**3+9**3=1010` so nope, this combination is not what we're looking for; digits may repeat in the result, not in our starting pick

Comment: @dratenik I guess that is my confusion. If I add a repeating number, like 9, I get `0**3+1**3+4**3+6**3+9**3+9**3=1739`, which is completely different than `1010`. I guess I don't understand how one can be sure that looking at the sum of calculating it for the non-repeating subset will ensure that no sum of repeating digits won't give a result of only containing the digits of the subset.

Comment: @Scratte ok, now I see the source of the confusion: I took "of its digits" in the problem to mean "of the set of its digits" (without repetition); if you want a solution for "of the list of its digits", I have nothing to say about that. And I don't immediately see how you would make *that* variant faster.

Comment: @dratenik Ohhh.. for 69950 using k=5 the sum is 6^5 + 9^5 + 9^5 + 5^5 + 0^5 = 128999 and without repeating 9 it's 69950. Thank you :) I understand your proposed solution now. I got the problem wrong, sorry :)